# Как создать сценарий?

Tags: windows, реестр

Как создать сценарий, обеспечивающий создание в реестре в разделе Hkey_Current_User собственного раздела, параметра и значения параметра с последующим запуском реестра в окне на  экран.

Answer (score 2):

1. Создайте REG-файл, содержащий необходимые параметры. Это можно сделать просто - использовав ф-цию экспорта в редакторе реестра.
2. Напишите пакетный файл, который будет запускать этот REG-файл.
3. Сделайте вызов в пакетном файле программы regedit.exe или regedt32.exe - зависит от версии винды. Тогда это запустит "реестр в окне на экране", если я правильно понял Вашу формулировку.